# View gets Distorted when GADInterstitial calls interstitialDidReceiveAd:

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, admob, uistatusbar

I am using google AdMob in my App. No problem in implementing the "GADInterstitial" which is used fo viewing google ads in full screen.

But the Problem is few times when the ads I show Distorts the view.
I used the following Code given at google Site:

```
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
{
[interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

I am adding some Pics for the reference

[image: View before ads delegate(mentioned above) gets called]

[image: The Ad shown in the Full Screen]
[image: View After I Press the cross button Ads View]

1 image is "View before ads delegate(mentioned above) gets called"

2 image is "The Ad shown in the Full Screen"

3 View After I Press the cross button Ads View

I don't understand why my navigation bar is pushed up; took the space of statues Bar too.

Moreover the ad above tabbar is also pushed up. It appears Status bar got Killed, and whole view Shifted up. The Images are for iPod4 touch having ios 6.1.

Same Problems I faced for iOS 7 on iphone 4, 5

Comment: Did you see status bar in iOS7 when full screen ads shows up?

Comment: @Maziyar let me check

Comment: Do you have status bar appear in your app at all? Because I have and I can't find the way to hide the status bar while the ads is presenting.

Comment: @Maziyar then Hide it Manually

Comment: The new AdMob SDK fixes this problem. It hides it automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know how this should be fixed. The view frame changes. Can anyone explain why this happens.

Comment: @user694688 what problem are you facing? are you sure you are using the latest sdk?